# How can we check if data is being generated for google analytics tracking profile?

Tags: google-analytics, servicenow

So we have google analytics setup for servicenow but from month of january we are unable to see data into reports I am looking for a way to figure out if data is being generated or not. can you suggest steps for the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to see in Browser Network if there is a call to Google Analytics servers, you can filter network traffic in the console with term: `collect`

However, if you no longer see the data in Google Analytics it means in most cases that you have removed the code from the page or that you have applied the wrong filter to the view. There are obviously other cases, it depends on the cases, those are the main ones.